# How to calculate input in entry in python (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to know how to calculate an expression in an entry? Let's say the input in the entry is 2+2. I want a variable to store that input not as a string but as an expression. I can't convert each number solely to floats so i dont know how. Here is the code im trying to use:

```
import pyautogui, math
from tkinter import *

def arithmetic_calc_press():
    global root
    root.destroy()
    arith_calc = Tk()
    bindings = {
        '<FocusIn>': {'default': 'active'},
        '<FocusOut>': {'default': 'active'}
    }
    for k, v in bindings.items():
        arith_calc.bind_class('Button', k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

    arith_calc.geometry('302x415')
    arith_calc.config(bg='black')

    enter_number = Entry(arith_calc, width=70, bg='black', fg='lime', bd=0)
    enter_number.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=100)

    def click(num):
        current = enter_number.get()
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
        enter_number.insert(0, str(current) + str(num))
    def back():
       arith_calc.destroy()
    def clear():
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
    def equal():
        global equal, f_num
        second_number = enter_number.get()
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
        if equal == 'plus':
            enter_number.insert(0, f_num + float(second_number))
        if equal == 'minus':
            enter_number.insert(0, f_num - float(second_number))
        if equal == 'mul':
            enter_number.insert(0, f_num * float(second_number))
        if equal == 'div':
            enter_number.insert(0, f_num / float(second_number))
    def plus():
        first_number = enter_number.get()
        global f_num, equal
        equal = 'plus'
        f_num = float(first_number)
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
    def minus():
        first_number = enter_number.get()
        global f_num, equal
        equal = 'minus'
        f_num = float(first_number)
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
    def mul():
        first_number = enter_number.get()
        global f_num, equal
        equal = 'mul'
        f_num = float(first_number)
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
    def div():
        first_number = enter_number.get()
        global f_num, equal
        equal = 'div'
        f_num = float(first_number)
        enter_number.delete(0, END)
        enter_number.delete(0, END)

    b7 = Button(arith_calc, text='7', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime", highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(7)).grid(row=1, column=0)
    b8 = Button(arith_calc, text='8', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(8)).grid(row=1, column=1)
    b9 = Button(arith_calc, text='9', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(9)).grid(row=1, column=2)
    b4 = Button(arith_calc, text='4', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(4)).grid(row=2, column=0)
    b5 = Button(arith_calc, text='5', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(5)).grid(row=2, column=1)
    b6 = Button(arith_calc, text='6', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(6)).grid(row=2, column=2)
    b1 = Button(arith_calc, text='1', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(1)).grid(row=3, column=0)
    b2 = Button(arith_calc, text='2', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(2)).grid(row=3, column=1)
    b3 = Button(arith_calc, text='3', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(3)).grid(row=3, column=2)
    b0 = Button(arith_calc, text='0', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                     highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: click(0)).grid(row=4, column=0)
    b_clear = Button(arith_calc, text='Clear', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=31, pady=20, command=clear).grid(row=4, column=2)
    b_plus = Button(arith_calc, text='+', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=40, pady=20, command=plus).grid(
        row=6, column=0)
    b_minus = Button(arith_calc, text='-', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=minus).grid(
        row=6, column=1)
    b_mul = Button(arith_calc, text='x', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=41, pady=20, command=mul).grid(
        row=5, column=1)
    b_div = Button(arith_calc, text=':', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                     highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=43, pady=20, command=div).grid(row=5,
                                                                                                                column=0)
    b_equal = Button(arith_calc, text='=', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=40, pady=20, command=equal).grid(row=4, column=1)
    b_decimal = Button(arith_calc, text='.', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                     highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=43, pady=52, command=lambda: click('.')).grid(row=5, column=2, rowspan=2)


def geometric_calc_press():
    pass

def quadratic_equation():
    global root
    root.destroy()
    quad_eq = Tk()
    bindings = {
        '<FocusIn>': {'default': 'active'},
        '<FocusOut>': {'default': 'active'}
    }
    for k, v in bindings.items():
        quad_eq.bind_class('Button', k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

    quad_eq.geometry('300x400')
    quad_eq.config(bg='black')
    def confirm():
        x = entry.get()
        print(float(x))
    label = Label(quad_eq, text='Enter a quadratic equation of the ', bg='black', fg='lime').pack()
    label2 = Label(quad_eq, text='form a*2x + bx + c or x*2 + px = q.', fg='lime', bg='black').pack()
    entry = Entry(quad_eq, bg='white', fg='black')
    entry.pack()
    confirm = Button(quad_eq, text='Confirm!', bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                     highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=34, pady=12, command=confirm).pack()
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')
bindings = {
    '<FocusIn>': {'default': 'active'},
    '<FocusOut>': {'default': 'active'}
}
for k, v in bindings.items():
    root.bind_class('Button', k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

root.title('Calculator')
root.config(bg='black')
Button(root, text='Arithmetic Calculator', padx=106, bg='black', fg='lime',highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime", highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', command=arithmetic_calc_press).grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(root, text='Geometric Calculator', padx=106, bg='black', fg='lime',highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime", highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', command=geometric_calc_press).grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(root, text='Quadratic Equation', padx=106, bg='black', fg='lime',highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime", highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', command=quadratic_equation).grid(row=0, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there something special I need to do. I wouldn't know bcuz I only have been programming for 3-4 months in python.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. What is the input and what is the desired output? You could use the `re` library to get the values from entry. Edit: Also include includes and code that is attempting to parse the input.

Comment: Sorry. I'll edit the question

Comment: Some advice for your code. The `tkinter` docs show it that way, but really avoid import globs (`from tkinter import *`) as much as possible do `from tkinter import Button, Tk, Label, ` instead. It can cause big issues with name collisions. Also avoid `global` and instead pass items or access them within an object. Another thing you might want to consider is making this a class that Extends `Tk.Frame` such as the example here (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program)